# Async data loading with WCF service with UI capabilities

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, asynchronous, telerik

I'm working on complex user control(with Telerik components).
I'm trying to implement following functionality:

1. Typing some text in RadTextBox(let say: "Hello.txt").
2. Clicking on Button "Check".
3. onClientClick for button "Check" will call WCF method with parameters.
    Let say that this request/response will take more that 10 seconds, 
    meanwhile I'll see loading image near TextBox AND the most important,
    I can continue to work on other fields.
4. When WCF service responses UI will be updated with the result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried calling the WCF using AJAX? Give us some info on the approach you tried so far as Rory mentioned.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238866/Invoke-Server-Methods-From-Client-Side-Using-JQuer), helped me to understand and implement the requested functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Make the wcf call a delegate so that it will call back the client when it has finished, leaving the client UI to continue in the meanwhile. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723737/wcf-callback-between-two-services/9724156#9724156) for instructions on how to do this.